# K-sample test for equality of distribution in time series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

I have a set of time series, with potentially very weird behavior (i.e. I'd prefer to make as few observations about them as possible, apart from stationarity, and don't want to model the time series directly). Luckily, they're all large. I'm interested in testing the hypothesis that both time series have the same marginal stationary distribution; are there any tests for that? For uncorrelated time series I can use the k-sample Anderson-Darling test, but I assume such a test would reject too often when the data are not independent.

Comment: *Which* distributions do you want to test?  Equality of marginals?  Equality of all bivariate distributions at all lags?  Or maybe just at specified lags?

Comment: Equality of marginals.